# `groupplots` array shows axes, but not the content being graphed

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to create a 2 * 2 array of XY graphs, each with a shaded region in one quadrant, and each with a label beneath. In other words, four variations on this:

[image]

(In case it's relevant, the code for that is

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[<->] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0);
    \draw[<->] (0,-5.5) -- (0,5.5);
    \draw[fill=gray]  (0,5) -- (5,5) -- (5,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    \node [below=5mm, align=flush center] at (0,-5)
        {
            Lorem ipsum
        };

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

)

It looked like the `groupplots` library was the way to go, so I did this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots} % LATEX and plain TEX

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[%
    group style={group size=2 by 2},
    height=3.5cm,
    width=3.5cm,
    /tikz/font=\small,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    xmin=-5.5,
    xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-5.5,
    ymax=5.5]
\nextgroupplot % parenthood
\draw[fill=gray]  (0,5) -- (5,5) -- (5,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\node [below=2mm, align=flush center] at (0,-5.5)
        {
            Parenthood
        };
\nextgroupplot % mountain climbing
\draw[fill=gray]  (0,0) -- (0,5) -- (-5,-5) -- (0,-5) -- cycle;
\node [below=5mm, align=flush center] at (0,-5)
        {
            Mountain climbing
        };
\nextgroupplot % Voting
\draw[fill=gray]  (0,-1) -- (-1,5) -- (5,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\node [below=5mm, align=flush center] at (0,-5)
        {
            Voting
        };
\nextgroupplot % TV
\draw[fill=gray]  (0,-5) -- (-5,-3) -- (0,-3) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\node [below=5mm, align=flush center] at (0,-5)
        {
            Television
        };
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Not quite what I was going for. Those little blips in the lower left of each graph are (I think) the shaded regions I was trying to draw; the axes are labeled with min and max values (which I didn't mean to do); and the labels are completely absent. What should I change to approximate more closely the original graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pgfplots does all sorts of coordinate transformations. But there is a very simple way to shade a region: use `ybar interval`s. And you can also add titles to the group plots instead of adding these nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots} % LATEX and plain TEX

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[%
    group style={group size=2 by 2},
    height=3.5cm,
    width=3.5cm,
    /tikz/font=\small,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    xmin=-5.5,
    xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-5.5,
    ymax=5.5,
    axis on top,xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty]
\nextgroupplot[title=Parenthood] % parenthood
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=gray] coordinates {(-5,-5) (0,0)};
\nextgroupplot[title=Mountain climbing] % mountain climbing
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=gray] coordinates {(-5,-5) (0,0)};
\nextgroupplot[title=Voting] % Voting
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=gray] coordinates {(-5,-5) (0,0)};
\nextgroupplot[title=TV] % TV
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=gray] coordinates {(-5,-5) (0,0)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I get rid of the numbers, so I just have the axis lines?

Comment: @crmdgn I made an update: `xticklabel=\empty`.